# Phase of a Wave and Phase Space

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, phase-space, bohmian-mechanics

What relation does the phase of a wave have with the phase space? Namely, how are they related historically and/or physically?

P.S. if it helps, I came across this question while thinking about the phase-space formulation of QM and the pilot-wave theory.

Comment: There's no relationship.  Two different uses of the same word.

Comment: [Phase space](http://physicstoday.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.3397041) in mechanics (hence QM) was probably introduced by Boltzmann in 1872: for periodic motions, the classical state is specified by energy and phase--think of the classical oscillator elliptic trajectories. Waves are periodic phenomena, so the wave phase quantifies position in the cycle, like the phases of the moon....  In phase-space QM, the two usage are aggressively disjoint, though.

Answer (score 1):

There is no relation between the phase of a wave and the so-called phase space of a mechanical system which consists of the space of all possible generalized coordinate and conjugate generalized momentum variables.